# What number of "connections" means on heroku Pusher add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, socket.io, comet, pusher

In Sandbox configuration, 20 connections means that only 20 users connected to a channel will recieve pusher notifications? If yes, what happens when more clients tries to connect?
If user opens multiple tabs (same IP), it will sums to connections number?

source: https://addons.heroku.com/pusher

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the FAQ on how connections are counted:
https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/202092346-How-are-connections-counted-

And for messages:
https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/200842913-How-is-my-message-count-calculated-

Comment: Thanks man! 20 connections is really bad. 100 connections is too small too.

Comment: The purpose of the free Sandbox plan is to let you develop your app or just have a play. The bootstrap plan is for just that - bootstrapping with a small number of users. If you are building something for non-commercial purposes then get in touch via the official Pusher channels: http://pusher.com/support